# Make div container clickable, except export button

Tags: jquery, highcharts, onclick

I want to create a Highcharts chart which whole `div` has an `onclick` function, but I don't want the Export Button to handle the event on the click. It should just react as a normal Export Button.

I have tried some jQuery tricks to avoid it, by getting the Highcharts Buttons class: `highcharts-button`, but it doesn't work :

```
jQuery("#container").on('click', ':not(.highcharts-button, .highcharts-button *)', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('CLICK');
    });
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t61e2z5o/). (Problem is: I don't want to see the alert pop when click the Export Button).

Comment: not getting you at alll can you please explain better way

Comment: @PranayRana Sorry. I want my chart to be clickable. This click creates an alert box. But I when I click on the ExportButton (Highcharts default button when creating a chart), I don't want this alert box to appear. Is it clearer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way could be to filter the event target, e.g:

```
jQuery("#container").on('click', function(e){      
    if ($(e.target).closest('.highcharts-button, .highcharts-contextmenu').length) return;
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('CLICK');
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: Oh, it works, but only for the first click. When I click one of the menu items, the event is handled. Should I use something like `.highcharts-button *` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [event.preventDefault()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp).  In your case e.preventDefault()

```
jQuery("#container").on('click', ':not(.highcharts-button, .highcharts-button *)', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('CLICK');
});
```

Comment: Nop it does not work. Have you tried on the JSFiddle before ? See : http://jsfiddle.net/t61e2z5o/3/

Comment: No I have not.  Sorry that didn't help.